# How can I retrieve an element

Tags: javascript, html, function, html-table

This is what I want to know. I have a table which has the number of rows depended on what the number is in the spinner. This does work e.g If I enter 25 in spinner it comes up with 25 rows, if I enter 7 in spinner comes with 7 rows.

So my problem is this:

Lets say there are a number of rows in a table. What I have is a textarea where the user enters in their question and then submits the question, the question should be inserted and appear in the first row of the table under the "Question" column, the textarea goes blank and the user enters in his second question, if the user submits this then the question would appear in the second row, 3rd question into 3rd row, 4th question 4th into row etc.

The problem is that everytime I submit a question into the table, it creates a new row. So if I had 20 empty rows in the table because I stated in the spinner I wanted 20 questions, then what happens is everytime I submit a question, it adds a new row everytime, so submitting 20 questions from the textarea would mean the table would contain 20 blank rows and 20 rows with questions. I am guessing it is because of this for example:

```
var enumeratorCell = document.createElement("td");
```

So what I want to know is how excepting creating an element to create a new row, how can I retrieve an element so that it submits the question in an existing row from top to bottom rather than creating a new row everytime a question is submitted?

```
Below is my code:

function insertQuestion() {   
var table = document.getElementById("qandatbl");
var tableBody = table.tBodies[0];
var textarea = document.getElementById("questionTxt");

var row = document.createElement("tr");
tableBody.appendChild(row);

var enumeratorCell = document.createElement("td");
enumeratorCell.className = "qid";
row.appendChild(enumeratorCell);

var questionCell = document.createElement("td");
questionCell.className = "question";
row.appendChild(questionCell);

var questionText = textarea.value;
var questionContent = document.createTextNode(questionText);
questionCell.appendChild(questionContent);

            }
```

HTML:

```
// table where questions will be inserted into

     <table>

    <?php
    $spinnerCount = $_POST['textQuestion'];
if($spinnerCount > 0) {
   for($i = 1; $i <= $spinnerCount; $i++) {?> // this get the number of questions from the spinner

        <tr>
            <td class="qid"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td class="question"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>


//Text Area and submit button to submit questions

<form id="enter" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<table id='middleDetails' border='1'>
<tr>
<th class='tblheading' colspan='2'>SESSION DETAILS</th>
</tr>
<tr class='trheight'>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="questionNum">Question No </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="questionContent">Question:</td> 
<td id="questionTextarea"><textarea rows="5" cols="40" id="questionTxt" name="questionText"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="addQuestionRow" colspan='2'><input id="addQuestion" type="button" value="Add Question" name="addQuestionBtn" onClick="insertQuestion()" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

What I am saying is there is a blank table, below table is a textarea and a submit button, teacher enters in a question and when teacher submits question, it goes in the first row in table as this is first question, then teacher repeats and 2nd question goes in row 2 and so on. But instead of inserting the data in the rows that are already in the table, it is creating new rows and inserting the data into new rows.

Comment: Malcolm, can you please rephrase your question. It is very difficult to make out what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: How does that tiny bit of PHP code in your HTML relate to the question? _"everytime I submit data into a table, it creates a new row"_ - when you say "submit" do you mean you have an existing HTML table on the page and you want to replace the contents of one or more TD elements with some new content or other? Maybe you could show the desired before and after state of your HTML?

Comment: What I am saying is there is a blank table, below table is a textarea and a submit button, teacher enters in a question and when teacher submits question, it goes in the first row in table as this is first question, then teacher repeats and 2nd question goes in row 2 and so on. But instead of inserting the data in the rows that are already in the table, it is creating new rows and inserting the data into new rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to do something like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableId); 
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");  
for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){           
    //manipulate rows  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an existing table:

```
<table id="myTable">
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to retrieve or change the contents of the existing cells you can do this:

```
// get reference to the table
var t = document.getElementById("myTable"),
    r,
    c,
    i, j;

// loop through the rows
for (i=0; i<t.rows.length; i++) {
   // get reference to current row
   r = t.rows[i]; //
   // loop through tds of current row
   for (j=0; j<r.cells.length; j++) {
       // get reference to current cell
       c = r.cells[j]; // equivalent to t.rows[i].cells[j]
      // display content of cell
      alert(c.innerHTML);
      // change content of cell
      c.innerHTML = "New value " + i + j;
    }
}
```

If you know the size of the table ahead of time you can directly reference a particular td - noting that the indexes start at 0, the third row's second td will be:

```
var particularTD = t.rows[2].cells[1]; // where t was declared above
alert(particularTD.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Can you do me a huge favour, can you code it for my existing table, it is because I look at your existing table and code and I am completley confused. I don't know what "New value" is or what r, j and c is. I would be hugely greatful if you do this for me

Comment: The code in my answer is an example. "New value" is just an example of a string that could be assigned to the inner html of the td element - it is up to you to substitute your own meaningful values. r, j and c are all just variables that I have declared. I used r to reference the current row in the outer loop, and c to reference the current cell (td element) in the inner loop. You need to read through my example very carefully (and/or google some JavaScript tutorials) until you understand it. My example is short and simple, so until you understand it you won't understand your own code...